# ios - Not adding backbutton to NavigationBar on ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, backbarbuttonitem

I can not add on NavigationBar backbutton. I want to perform this operation on a ViewController, I have tried different ways, but could not reach a solution. Do you need to use Backbutton NavigationController to use, or you can perform on a ViewController?
Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your ViewController is within a navigation controller, you should be able to do this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: No,  ViewController not in the NavigationController, I want to go back with the button back of two separate ViewController, but the back button to don't show it on the page.

Answer (score -1):

Hide the default back button

```
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];

    UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow.png"]  ;
    [backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goback) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 23);
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn] ;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;

- (void)goback
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```